# Connecting monitor to mac via USB docking

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, usb, display, dock

I just bought a new BenQ GL2450 monitor to connect to my macbook pro 13" late 2011. I try to connect it with a DVI cable and via a USB docking that goes into my laptop, but the screen says no signal and my laptop does not recognise any monitor. The USB docking works perfectly fine with my keyboard, mouse and even my M-Audio Fastrack Ultra 8R USB interface. So could it be that the signal simply won't go through a USB cable and that I need to find an adapter and plug it directly into my mini displayport or something? Because it would be way much more simple to just connect one USB cable and have everything connected already.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

What is the docking station?  Without knowing, as a guess, I'd say yes, you will have to get video via the mini-DP.  USB and Firewire and such are not really designed to carry video signals, and while some USB docks do video, the laptop needs to support this properly - something that my MBP does not do at all.

I get the convenience, but the mini-DP is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that you cannot connect the monitor through the USB port. The mini-displayport is the way to go, imo. Have you considered connecting using HDMI through an HDMI/mini display port adapter? If your monitor has HDMI that's an option, and not too pricey.